# HTTP POST request returns Unauthenticated error in Angular

Tags: angular, api, http, post, error-handling

```js
add_product(token: string,data:any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${API_USERS_URL}/products/create`, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**
Try
**

```
return this.http.post<any>(`${API_USERS_URL}/products/create`,data, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have see on your back-end may be CORS error are there, if CORS is enable, disable it and then try it.
also try with this code.

```
 httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +'token'}) };
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { };
    getData(): Observable<string> {
        return this.httpClient.post<string>(Constant.BASE_URL + "UserReaction/deleteUserReaction", { "data": { 'userReactionId': 'userReactionId' } }, this.httpOptions).pipe(retry(3), catchError(Constant.handleError));
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir your answer is advance and i am beginner @Sudhanshu Maurya save me

Comment: @MuhammadAmir you can just try it hope so it will solve your problem.